# what is defaultIconSet() in AngularJs Material and how i use it?

Tags: angularjs, svg, material-design, angular-material

i follow some angularjs material tutorials to build a template using angular material.

When i start to configure svg icons using the icon provider there is some thing called  defaultIconSet() :

```
 // Register the user `avatar` icons
        $mdIconProvider
  .defaultIconSet("./app/assets/svg/avatars.svg", 128)
  .icon("menu", "./app/assets/svg/menu.svg", 24)
  .icon("share", "./app/assets/svg/share.svg", 24)
  .icon("google_plus", "./app/assets/svg/google_plus.svg", 24)
  .icon("hangouts", "./app/assets/svg/hangouts.svg", 24)
  .icon("twitter", "./app/assets/svg/twitter.svg", 24)
  .icon("phone", "./app/assets/svg/phone.svg", 24);
```

Now i can use all the other icons in my views for example:

```
 <md-icon md-svg-icon="twitter"></md-icon>
```

but i don't understand how can i use the avatar images or what is the function of defaultIconSet() also i didn't found help in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

It loads a set of icons through their default name.

Please, [refer to the doc](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdIconProvider).

> $mdIconProvider.defaultIconSet(url, [viewBoxSize]); Register a source
>   URL for the default 'named' set of icons. Unless explicitly
>   registered, subsequent lookups of icons will failover to search this
>   'default' icon set. Icon can be retrieved from this cached, default
>   set using $mdIcon()